# Using DatePicker and TimePicker dialog boxes - Android Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datepicker, timepicker

I have no errors on the code, but when I launch I get a fatal error in my main XML page that says,

> 03-21 22:00:31.849: E/AndroidRuntime(606): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{countrycabin.ist236/countrycabin.ist236.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm not sure what is causing the problem. As I said, I have no errors. I made a program very similar to this that worked fine, I just added the TimePicker to this one.

What I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward. I'm making the program launch, and when I click a button, a dialog displays that shows either a DatePicker or TimePicker, and when someone selects a date words display in a TextView at the bottom. I'm unable to test even this, however, as it will not even launch. My emulator tells me it will not respond.

I'm using Honeycomb for this, as stated in a textbook.

Here is all my code.

Main Manifest XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="countrycabin.ist236"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="countrycabin.ist236.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

main XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  tools:context=".Main" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCabin"
    android:layout_width="282dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/strCabin"
    android:src="@drawable/cabin" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#666FFF"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:text="@string/strTitle"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="25dp"
            android:text="@string/strDesc"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        </TableRow>



        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:contentDescription="@string/strRad" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radCabin1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="@string/strCabinOne"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radCabin2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:text="@string/strCabinTwo"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </RadioGroup>



    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDate"
            android:layout_width="50dp"

            android:padding="20sp"
            android:text="@string/strDate"
            android:textSize="25sp" />



    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

          <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnTime"
             android:layout_width="50dp"

             android:padding="20sp"
             android:text="@string/strTime"
             android:textSize="25sp" />


    </TableRow>

       <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </TableRow>

       <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

       </TableRow>


</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main class (Java code)

```
package countrycabin.ist236;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker; 
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class Main extends Activity {

private int currentYear;
private int currentMonth;
private int currentDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
int hour;
int minute;
String cabin1 = "The Wooden Castle";
String cabin2 = "Cozy Little Spot";
private Button btDate;
private Button btTime;
private TextView timeDisplay;
private TextView dateDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    dateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);

    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);

    btDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



     btTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    }
});
final Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance();
hour = d.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minute = d.get(Calendar.MINUTE);



}


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id){
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, reservationDate, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeDate, hour, minute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener reservationDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    final RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCabin1);
    final RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCabin2);
        @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    if(c1.isChecked()){


        dateDisplay.setText("Your rental time is set for " + (month + 1) + "-" + day + "-" + year + " to " + (month + 1) + "-" + (day + 3) + "-" + year + " in " + cabin1 + ".");
    }
    if(c2.isChecked()){
        dateDisplay.setText("Your rental time is set for " + (month + 1) + "-" + day + "-" + year + " to " + (month + 1) + "-" + (day + 3) + "-" + year + " in " + cabin2 + ".");
    }
    }

};

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeDate = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hours, int minutes) {
        timeDisplay.setText("Your arrival time will be at " + hours + ":" + minutes + ".");
    }
};



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: can you tried to clean your workspace.Goto Project->Clean and select your projec.because of sometime manifext.xml  doesn't build automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Code: Its working fine now.

[image]

I have made some change in XML file as well as in Your Activity now its working fine

**But You have to made some changes depend on your requirement.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCabin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="strCabin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#666FFF"
                android:text="strTitle"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="strDesc"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="strRad" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radCabin1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="strCabinOne"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radCabin2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                    android:text="strCabinTwo"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDate"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:text="strDate"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTime"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:text="strTime"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private int currentYear;
    private int currentMonth;
    private int currentDay;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    String cabin1 = "The Wooden Castle";
    String cabin2 = "Cozy Little Spot";
    private Button btDate;
    private Button btTime;
    private TextView timeDisplay;
    private TextView dateDisplay;
    private RadioButton c1;
    private RadioButton c2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        timeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        dateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
        c1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCabin1);
        c2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radCabin2);
        btDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        btTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, reservationDate, currentYear,
                    currentMonth, currentDay);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeDate, hour, minute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener reservationDate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            if (c1.isChecked()) {

                dateDisplay.setText("Your rental time is set for "
                        + (month + 1) + "-" + day + "-" + year + " to "
                        + (month + 1) + "-" + (day + 3) + "-" + year + " in "
                        + cabin1 + ".");
            }
            if (c2.isChecked()) {
                dateDisplay.setText("Your rental time is set for "
                        + (month + 1) + "-" + day + "-" + year + " to "
                        + (month + 1) + "-" + (day + 3) + "-" + year + " in "
                        + cabin2 + ".");
            }
        }

    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeDate = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hours, int minutes) {
            timeDisplay.setText("Your arrival time will be at " + hours + ":"
                    + minutes + ".");
        }
    };

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```