# timepicker listener cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datepicker, timepicker

I have been searching for hours with no luck. I am using Eclipse to create an Android App with a timepicker and datepicker, the datepicker works fine when I call on a timepicker listener in OnCreateDialog it comes up with the timePickerListener cannot be resolved to a variable error.

I have followed a whole heap of examples for which to me it looks like I'm replicating but can't get rid of this error. In particular the resolution at the bottom of this question

[Using DatePicker and TimePicker dialog boxes - Android Java in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561112/using-datepicker-and-timepicker-dialog-boxes-android-java-in-eclipse?rq=1)

My java code is as follows:

```
private TextView tvDisplayDate;
private DatePicker dpResult;
private TimePicker timepicker;
private Button infringementbutton;
private Button timebutton;
private TextView tvDisplayDate2;
private TextView tvDisplayTime;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private int yearA;
private int monthA;
private int dayA;
private int hour;
private int minute;


static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();
    }


    // display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    tvDisplayDate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateA);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);



    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1


        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42);
    dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1


    .append(dayA).append("-").append(monthA + 1).append("-")
    .append(yearA).append(" "));


    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}
//Display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {
    tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);



    // set current time into textview
            tvDisplayTime.setText(
                        new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                                           .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            // set current time into timepicker
            timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    infringementbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infringementbutton);
timebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timebutton);

    infringementbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });
 timebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {


    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);
       break;

    switch (id) {

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);}
    return null;


}}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;



        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,42);
        dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder()
        .append(dayA).append("-").append(monthA + 1).append("-").append(yearA)
           .append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);



    }


    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            // set current time into textview
            tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            // set current time into timepicker
            timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

        }
    };  
};


private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

Here's the main.xml

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1">

<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableRow>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/infringementbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/infringement"
     />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</TableRow><TableRow>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/penaltydate" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDateA"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
  <TableRow >   

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/timebutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/time"
     />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timepicker"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
```

Hopefully the code isn't too confusing cos I'm only new at this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Which line of code specifically causes the error? There's a lot there to read.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. check the docs.

Comment: i'm not sure which line exactly but its almost down the bottom in the OnCreateDialog method under the TIME_DIALOG_ID case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have commented the layout related code as i dnt have it nd u have not post it ....
once check ths out and let me knw ...

public class DialogScreen extends Activity {
    private TextView tvDisplayDate;
    private DatePicker dpResult;
    private TimePicker timepicker;
    private Button infringementbutton;
    private Button timebutton;
    private TextView tvDisplayDate2;
    private TextView tvDisplayTime;

```
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private int yearA;
private int monthA;
private int dayA;
private int hour;
private int minute;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();
}

// display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    tvDisplayDate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateA);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1

            .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
            .append(year).append(" "));

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42);
    dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1

            .append(dayA).append("-").append(monthA + 1).append("-")
            .append(yearA).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}

// Display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {
    tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);

    // set current time into textview
    tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
            .append(pad(minute)));

    // set current time into timepicker
    timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    infringementbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infringementbutton);
    timebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timebutton);

    infringementbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });
    timebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                false);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" "));

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42);
        dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayA).append("-")
                .append(monthA + 1).append("-").append(yearA).append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

    }

};
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        // set current time into textview
        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

        // set current time into timepicker
        timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
        timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    }
};

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
```

}

XML Resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infringementbutton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Infringement" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dpResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Penaltydate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDateA"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timebutton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timepicker"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: That's done it, I can't even pick up what you changed but it worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few missed placed `{` which is very hard to find out.
You can have one switch statement.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day); // return here
       break; //then break 

    switch (id) { // then switch again no need for another switch

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);}
    return null; 
}
}
```

Also some methods are deprecated.So i suggest you look at the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html.

Has detailed exaplanation of both time picker and date picker along with code snippets.

```
public class pickerdate extends Activity {

private TextView tvDisplayDate;
private DatePicker dpResult;
private TimePicker timepicker;
private Button infringementbutton;
private Button timebutton;
private TextView tvDisplayDate2;
private TextView tvDisplayTime;

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private int yearA;
private int monthA;
private int dayA;
private int hour;
private int minute;


static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();
    }


    // display current date
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

      tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
      tvDisplayDate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateA);
      dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);



    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1


        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
        .append(year).append(" "));

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 42);
    dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1


    .append(dayA).append("-").append(monthA + 1).append("-")
    .append(yearA).append(" "));


    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

}
//Display current time
public void setCurrentTimeOnView() {
    tvDisplayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepicker);



    // set current time into textview
            tvDisplayTime.setText(
                        new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                                           .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            // set current time into timepicker
            timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    infringementbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.infringementbutton);
    timebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timebutton);

    infringementbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });
 timebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {


    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
       // set date picker as current date
       return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, 
                     year, month,day);

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, 
                timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
        }
    return null;



  }

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
            = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;



        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
           .append(" "));

        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,42);
        dayA = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        monthA = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        yearA = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        tvDisplayDate2.setText(new StringBuilder()
        .append(dayA).append("-").append(monthA + 1).append("-").append(yearA)
           .append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
    }
    };


    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;

            // set current time into textview
            tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                    .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            // set current time into timepicker
            timepicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            timepicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

        }
    };  



private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using one switch statement at one point but couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Joel also i would suggest you to use the one in the docs since some methods are deprecated in newer api versions